# toggle class if else css

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I would like an element to become fixed when the 'push' class is added and then become relative again when the class 'push' is removed.

This is what I have:

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function() {
    $('.wrapper,header,nav').toggleClass('push', function() {
        if ($('.wrapper,header,nav').hasClass('push')) {
            $('.wrapper').css('position', 'fixed');
        } else {
            $('.wrapper').css('position', 'relative');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the css:

```
.push {
left:200px;
position:fixed;
}
.wrapper {
position:relative;
float:left;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:2;
background:#fff;
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
}
nav {
position:fixed;
line-height:50px;
margin-left:-200px;
z-index:0;
width:200px;
height:100%;
float:left;
color:#fff;
background:#030e17;
}
header {
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
float:left;
width:100%;
background:#fff;
border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks

Comment: Not without your HTML

Comment: why not just add `.push { position:fixed; }` to your style sheet or if just targeting your wrapper: `.wrapper.push { position:fixed; }`?

Comment: [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) has no overload like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't want all elements to become `fixed`, so you can't add `position: fixed` to `.push` CSS class declaration. However you can make additional rule for `.wrapper` only:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper.push {
    position: fixed;
}
```

And you JS will become:

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function() {
    $('.wrapper, header, nav').toggleClass('push');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have function in toggleclass. (it does not need this)

Try:

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function () {
    $('.wrapper,header,nav').toggleClass('push');

        if ($('.wrapper,header,nav').hasClass('push')) {
            $('.wrapper').css('position', 'fixed');
        } else {
            $('.wrapper').css('position', 'relative');
        }

});
```

Here is working demo:  (inspect element);

http://jsfiddle.net/LuwLn962/

Answer (score 0):

//Toggle class With Css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.left-panel{
height:200px;
background:red;
width:30px;
float:left;

}
.div1{
background:#cecece;
width:25%;
height:300px;
float:left;
top:0;
position:relative;
}
.div2{
background:#333333;
width:68%;
height:300px;
float:left;
top:0;
position:relative;
}


</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".left-panel").click(function(){

if($( ".div1" ).css( "display")=="block")
{

$(".div1").hide("slow"); 
$( ".div2:visible" ).animate({

    width: "+=350px"

}, "slow" );

}
else
{

$(".div1").show("slow");
$( ".div2:visible" ).animate({

    width: "-=350px"

}, "slow" ); 

}

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left-panel"></div><div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```